# Defining custom css attributes and changing any value with animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to make a result screen in javascript that displays animated scores. For the specific field in the example it's supposed to go from the value to 0 in two seconds, two seconds after the screen appears. Since it's easy to change css values with `animate()` I thought I could assign the values to some custom css property, then have the element's value take it from there. According to [this article](http://thatemil.com/blog/2013/12/15/playing-around-with-css-variables-custom-properties/) I just have to place `--` in front of custom css attributes and [this one](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-jquery-animate-method/) shows me how to use the `animate()` method. So I tried doing this

```
$elementSuccess.css('--value', scorePlus);
```

and it turns out `--value`'s value is `undefined`. When I display `scorePlus` somewhere it appears, so it's defined. Is there another way to define a custom value?

Here is the entire code for this element. Will there be any errors with it if a custom attribute is defined correctly?

```
$elementSuccess.html(scorePlus);
$elementSuccess.css('--value', scorePlus);
setTimeout(function(){
    $elementSuccess.animate({
            '--value': 0
        },
        {
            duration: 2000,
            progress: function(){
                $elementSuccess.html(Math.round($elementSuccess.css('--value')));
            }
        }
    );
},2000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var scorePlus=100;
var $elementSuccess=$('.success');
var myObject = {score:scorePlus};
$elementSuccess.html(scorePlus);
$(myObject).delay(2000).animate({score:0},{duration:2000,progress:function(){$elementSuccess.html(Math.round(myObject.score))}});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="success"></div>
```

Based on my understanding of your problem, basically using a pseudo `myObject` and animating its `score` property should provide you with the desired effect. Also, instead of `setTimeout`, I resorted to using [`delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/).